# Transaction stucked in queue in the middle of purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am testing my in app purchase with test accound and all whent good. I accidently figure out some problem. I was in the middle of purchase, the alert went on "do you want to buy..." and I pressed HOME button, when I started again application, it did not clear queue? so I started receiving pop up to log in ... it was stucked in queue. I need help, how to implement if app terminate, to automaticly clear queue. So if some can post code for that . Tnx

Comment: You should add some more context. We have no idea what it is you're doing based on your question. Post some relevant code, did you also read Apple's documentation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this by puting observer in appDelegate.

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var transactionObserver: PurchaseViewController!



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    transactionObserver = PurchaseViewController()
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(transactionObserver)

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    transactionObserver = PurchaseViewController()
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(transactionObserver)
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    transactionObserver = PurchaseViewController()
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(transactionObserver)
}


}
```